# Getting data generated in putty Application using COM objects in python

Tags: python, com

I am trying to write application which uses WSH scripting under Python for automation purpose. I used  win32com.client module to get shell and run the putty application to access routers. Iam able to access the devices and send the key strokes and commands to putty GUI window. But the problem is,I want to track the ongoing command status which was sent using COM object.How can I read/get the buffer data of application initiated by COM object.Is there any easy way?Can I can get the data in python variable which is returned by device in putty ! Please help..`

```
import time
import win32api
import win32com.client
shell = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("WScript.Shell")

shell.Run("putty")
time.sleep(1)
shell.SendKeys("192.168.1.x")
shell.SendKeys(r"show version | no-more")  #command to run on putty   
 console
time.sleep(2)
shell.SendKeys("~")
```

Thanks,
Sat

Comment: If you do not need to respond so real-time, how about letting Putty output it to a log file and reading it? Specifying 'FLUSH LOG FILE FREQUENTLY' may improve a little. [4.2 THE LOGGING PANEL](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/putty/putty-manuals/0.68/Chapter4.html#config-logging)

Comment: Or try using this WinSCP-based product instead of Putty. [WinSCP .NET Assembly and COM Library](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library)